# Help with the notation of the definition of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

My textbook gives the following statement as of what a vector space is:

Let $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$. A vector space onto $\mathbb{F}$ consists of a non empty set $V$, a representation $V$x$V \rightarrow V, (u_1,u_2) \mapsto u_1 + u_2$, which is called addition and a representation $(\mathbb{F}$x$V) \rightarrow V, (λ,u) \mapsto λu$, which is called scalar multiplication of an element of $\mathbb{F}$ with an element of V, for which the following axioms are true: ...

Can someone explain what the notation that we used for the addition and multiplication mean? e.g. what does $V$x$V$ mean, and why is this arrow $\mapsto$ used? What does it mean in this context? Thank you!

Comment: $V\times V$ is the Cartesian product of $V$ with itself (ie, the set $\{(u_1,u_2)\mid u_1,u_2\in V\})$ and $\mapsto$ is a shorthand for map (ie, a function)

Comment: Does the book really say "vector space **onto** $\mathbb F$"? The more usual language is "**over** $\mathbb F$".

Comment: Just a note on language (math in English): the word you've translated as "representation" should be translated as "operation" in this situation. It's probably worth learning this, as "representation" has a mathematical meaning that is very specific and quite different from this use of "operation".

Comment: Oh, and BTW, don't worry too much about that: other than that word and "onto" vs. "over", your English is really good. I think we're only pointing out those two words precisely because everything else is so spot on -- and I appreciate it when people point out when I've gotten something a bit off when I'm using a foreign language.

Answer (score 1):

$V \times V$ is a notation for the cartesian product. The elements of $V \times V$ are basically ordered the pairs $(v_1,v_2)$ with $v_1,v_2 \in V$. In general when you have two sets $A,B$, $A \times B$ denotes the the set containing all the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a \in A, b \in B$.

The $\mapsto$ symbol denotes what your map does with the elements. Its the same thing as writing $\varphi((v_1,v_2))=v_1+v_2$ in your example.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the cartesian product consists of *orderered* pairs, i.e. $(v_1,v_2)$ is not the same as $(v_2,v_1)$ unless $v_1 = v_2$.

Comment: @Bungo thank you for pointing that out, edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, $V\times V$ means the space created in 2 dimensions by all possible combinations of $V$ with itself.

For example, the *[cartesian plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)* is a space in two dimensions which could be described as $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$. In fact, we can construct every ordered pair in the cartesian plane by choosing any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(a, b) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Note that $a$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ but $(a, b)$ is in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you want an ordered tern you would also choose $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(a, b, c) \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The arrow means its an **application** from V into V. Recall that you used that same notation for functions: $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{D}$ is the domain of $f$.
Well, a function is a particular case of an application from the set $\mathbb{D}$ to the set $\mathbb{R}$. Instead of a function one could have another application from a set to another, for example, a *Transformation* from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Or $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: this explanation should be marked as the correct answer. Very clear!

Comment: @rato Well, except the last part about applications vs func5ions which is not correct. They are just functions. The word application is not used in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The Cartesian product $V\times V$ is the set of ordered pairs of vectors of $V$.

Addition is a binary operation, or a function from $V\times V$ to $V$;

this can be written as $+:V\times V\to V $.

The "maps to" symbol "$\mapsto$" shows where a function takes an individual element;

e.g., $+:(v_1,v_2)\mapsto v_1+v_2$.

Scalar multiplication is a function from $\mathbb F\times V$ to $V$,

mapping the ordered pair $(\lambda,v)$ to $\lambda v$, where $\lambda\in\mathbb F$ and $v\in V$.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol $A \to B$ is general set theory shorthand for "a function with domain $A$ and range $B$". Often functions come with names, in which case one would put the name first, like this: $f : A \to B$, which means "a function, named $f$, with domain $A$ and range $B$". So without the name, one might also read $A \to B$ as "an unnamed function with domain $A$ and range $B$.

The notation $A \times B$ is general set theory notation for "the cartesian product of a set $A$ and a set $B$".

You might benefit from finding an account of basic set theory notation and usage. Undergraduate textbooks on the "foundations of mathematics" will contain these kinds of things, and sometimes more advanced textbooks will contains these in an introductory section. I quite like the introduction of Munkres "Topology" for that purpose, although that's quite an investment if all you want is to learn some linear algebra.

Comment: It seems like you accidentally posted this answer twice.

Comment: Oops. That happens to me now and then when I'm hopping from one window to another, but I can't figure it out exactly.

Answer (score 0):

To say that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathcal{F}$ means that there is an "addition" function and a "scalar multiplication" function. Addition is a function $a:V\times V\rightarrow V$, where $V\times V$ is the set of ordered pairs of elements in $V$, i.e. an element of $V\times V$ is an ordered pair $(v,w)$ with $v$ and $w$ in $V$. We often write $a(v,w)=v+w$, or alternatively we say that the function $a$ is given by $(v,w)\mapsto v+w$ (the arrow $\mapsto$ is used in this way throughout all of mathematics). Scalar multiplication is a function $m:\mathcal{F}\times V\rightarrow V$, where as above $\mathcal{F}\times V$ is ordered pairs of elements $(\lambda, v)$ where $\lambda$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ and $v$ is in V. We often write $m(\lambda,v) = \lambda v$, or alternatively we say that $m$ is given by $(\lambda, v)\mapsto \lambda v$. We further require that these functions $a$ and $m$ respect each other in certain ways, but hopefully this clears up some of the notational confusion.